# Compressing a Base 62(0-9a-zA-Z) encoded string

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression

I need to compress a base62 (0-9a-zA-Z) encoded string with a length of 20 characters into a 15-16 character string in order to squeeze some other information in. The tricky part is the compressed output should also be base62 encoded. Can this be done? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How about leaving it as-is? `decode (encode data)` is the identity function, isn't it?

Comment: Is your destination String ASCII or e.g 16bit-unicode?

Comment: No hope to achive this. As says @H2CO3 : "encode to compress" will give a small compression advangage, which will be lost by "decode to base62". Output will be same length as input.

Comment: Is the original string alphanumeric? How is the base62-encoding done?

Comment: t can be done with output of 20 bytes but not base62 encoded.

20 characters in base 62 means 20 * (log62/log2) Bits are needed to encode it. (this are about 120 Bits = 15 bytes) so you can store them in 15 Bytes
Sf you can store 20 bytes (instead of 20 base62 encoded characters) it is possible.

Comment: thanks everyone for the quick responses, @MrSmith42 Yes both the source and destination strings are alpha numeric.

Comment: @TerjeD. base62 encoding is done by converting a number to base 62 representation by using the alpha numeric characters (i.e 1-9 + a-z + A-Z) similar to hexadecimal.

Comment: I know how to encode using base62, but the question is _what_ is encoded. _e.g_ if it is ascii characters, 12.5% compression is obtained by removing the most significant bits (all zeroes) before encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) - if you try to put 100 pigeons into 10 holes, some holes will have multiple pigeons. In the same way, for your problem, there will have to be occurrences of two strings compressing to the same string. In these cases, you won't know which string to decompress the compressed string to.

So no, you cannot [losslessly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) compress 20 characters to 16 characters (or even 20 to 19 characters) in the same encoding for all possible inputs.

---

If the input were to have some defining characteristics, such as that the only uppercase character will be the first character, the last 3 characters are where the numbers appears, etc., then it will be more compressible and it may be possible.

If you had such characteristics (or if you want to convert to a different encoding that has enough space), you could easily convert a string in any encoding to a unique number and then this number into a string in a different encoding. The way to do this would be to:

- For each character position, assign a number, starting at 0, to each possible character allowed in that position.

  So if "A" to "Z" and "a" to "z" is allowed in the first position, you could assign 0-25 to "A" through "Z" and 26-51 to "a" through "z". So "B", for example, will be 1.
- Iterate through the string, multiplying the total by the number of allowable values for the current position and then adding the number assigned to the character at that position to the total.

To get a different encoding, just repeatedly:

- Set the total to the result of dividing the total by number of allowable values for the current position (rounding down).
- Set the current position to the character corresponding to the remainder of the above division.

It doesn't matter if you go from left to right or right to left in either of the above cases, as long as pick one way and stick to it.

You could also easily determine if such a conversion is possible by calculating the maximum possible value for each encoding (by taking the largest value for each character) - if the target has a smaller largest possible value, the conversion is not possible.

Note that the above is only for when certain positions have fixed values, although you can, to some extent, extend this to work for other encodings (such as having at most 1 number in the string), but this gets a bit more complex.

Example:

> **Input format:** 1 uppercase letter (A-Z), then 2 digits (0-9)
>   **Output format:** 1 lowercase letter (a-z), then 2 upper-/lowercase letters (A-Z or a-z)
>   **Input:** "Z35"
>   **Number:** 10*(10*(26*0 + 25) + 3) + 5 = 2535
>   **Explanation:** We start with "Z", the total is 0 to start, which we multiply by the number of uppercase letters (26) and then add the value for "Z" (25). We then move on to "3", where we multiple this total by the number of digits (10) and add the value for "3" (3), and so on.
>   **Output calculation:**
>   2535 / 26 = 97
>   2535 % 26 = 13, so 1st character = "n" (13+1 = 14th letter of alphabet)
>   97 / 52 = 1
>   97 % 52 = 45, so 2nd character = "t" (45-26+1 = 20th letter of alphabet)
>   1 % 52 = 1, so 3rd character = "B"
>   **Output:** "ntB"
>
> **Largest possible value for input format:** 10*(10*(26*0 + 25) + 9) + 9 = 2599
>   **Largest possible value for output format:** 52*(52*(26*0 + 25) + 51) + 51 = 70303
>   **Is conversion possible?** Yes, because 70303 >= 2599.