# Trimming a 64 bit unique number to smaller length

Tags: encryption

I have a 64 bit unique number. Is there a possibility to trim this number or use a crypto function to obtain a 48 bit unique number?

Thanks a lot in advance

I think I was not clear enough. I don't want to compress or recover original input. I just have a flash memory that already have a 64 bit unique ID programmed from factory, and some RF ZigBee stack needs a 48 bit number as unique node ID.

It's possible from 64 input to obtain 48 that is guaranteed to be unique?

If I compute CRC32 over something (like a string, block of data) I will obtain a 32 bit value that I'm not 100% sure, but supposed to be unique.

Likewise, can I compute a 48 bit CRC (but don't know how) or use some other checksum/hash to obtain exact 48 bit as output.

Thanks very much,

Comment: If you encrypt something it can only get bigger or stay the same, but never smaller. And I doubt there is a compression algorithm that produces good results for such small payloads.

Comment: I'm thinking about something similar to CRC but I need to produce 48 bits that are unique

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compressing a Base 62(0-9a-zA-Z) encoded string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670977/compressing-a-base-620-9a-za-z-encoded-string)

Comment: How many numbers do you have? When hashing down you'll run into collisions as you approach a few million entries. If the unique number has no structure you can exploit, hashing is the best stateless approach.